# Transform custom tags with arguments

Tags: text-processing, markdown

I want to write my diploma theses with markdown. Sadly, there is no perfect editor and so I have to improvise. For bibtex citations I want to transform my own definition with some sort of bash-filter right before I handle the input to pandoc:

```
<@BIBTEX_ID[|OPTIONAL_PAGE_OR_CHAPTER_NUM[|OPTIONAL_UNIT_DEFINITION]]>
```

to something like:

```
\autocite[OPTIONAL_UNIT_DEFINITION][OPTIONAL_PAGE_OR_CHAPTER_NUM]{BIBTEX_ID}
```

example:

```
<@sample>       ---> \autocite{sample}
<@sample|12>    ---> \autocite[12]{sample}
<@sample|12|c.> ---> \autocite[12][c.]{sample}
```

which bash/unix tool can do this job? Would it be possible to do it with sed or awk?

Comment: With `sed` you could probably do this quite easily. Did you try that? But really, why are you doing these kind of work-arounds? I fail to see the benefit. Bibtex is quite powerful in combination with your reference-database of choice.

Comment: Cause my editor does not support pandoc citations like `[see @blubb]` and always creates footnotes, which is really annoying and I don't want to put latex directly into my markdownfiles. <@blubb> would be much more nicer than \autocite{blubb}.

Comment: Off-topic advice: don't use markdown for something that's complex enough to need citations. Use LaTeX, you'll suffer less.

Comment: @Gilles is right about this one. Having just finished a thesis myself, I can tell you that using LaTeX with biblatex is a dream. WYSIWYG editors (or markdown) will make everything harder down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this straightforwardly:

```
sed -e 's/<@\([^|>]*\)|\([^|>]*\)|\([^>|]*\)>/\\autocite[\2][\3]{\1}/g' \
    -e 's/<@\([^|>]*\)|\([^|>]*\)>/\\autocite[\2]{\1}/g' \
    -e 's/<@\([^|>]*\)>/\\autocite{\1}/g'
```

This just replaces each possible formulation separately: the first handles three-parameter citations, then two, then one. Each optional block is matched with `\([^|>]*\)`, and they're substituted into the output with `\1...3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^<@\([^|]*\)\(.*\)>/!b
    s//\\autocite\2{\1}/
    s/|/[/;s/|/][/g;/\[/s/{/]{/
' <<\DATA
<@sample>
<@sample|12>
<@sample|12|c.>
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
\autocite{sample} 
\autocite[12]{sample}
\autocite[12][c.]{sample}
```

The first thing `sed` does is verify the line it is working on begins with `<@` followed at some point by a `>`. If the line does not match that pattern it `b`ranches out of the script to begin the next line cycle and try again.

But if it does match `sed` does a little double-duty by referencing `\1` with all or any characters following `@` which are not the `|` character and referencing `\2` with all or any characters following the first sequence until the last occurrence of `>` on the line. On the next line - which is only reached if the first line matches - `sed` borrows those references from the first address and replaces the whole string with `\\autocite\2{\1}`.

On the following line `sed` attempts to replace the first occurrence of the `|` character with a `[`, then any more `|` characters with `][`, and, last, if a `[` exists on the line it replaces the first occurrence of `{` with `]{`.

Everything `sed` does is straightforward. Everything `sed` does is a direct result of the thing it has just done. `sed` is conspicuously - and sometimes annoyingly - orderly.

And by the way - this should handle as many `|` separated parameters as you could care to specify on a single line - it is not limited to two. The `[<>@|{}]` tokens and line-placement must be respected though - at least as written. As long as you follow the rules, `sed` surely won't break any.